# Input Text overflow inside HTML table

Tags: html, css

I wanted to develop a calculator using Javascript. I am stuck in the design. The text box display is going beyond the border of the table cell. Following is the

```css
 /*The Style file is the following*/
 
 table{
     border:1px solid silver;
     border-radius:5px;
    }
    
    .btn{
     width:75px;
     height:45px;
    }
    
    #equalToBtn{
     background-color:blue;
     color:white;
     border-color:blue;
    }
    
    #resultText{
     width:100%;
     height:40px;
     margin-right:2px;
    }
```

```html
<!--HTML code-->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
     </head>
     <body>
      <table>
       <tr>
       <td colspan="4"><input type="text" id="resultText"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">7</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">8</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">9</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">/</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">4</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">5</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">6</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">*</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">1</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">2</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">3</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">-</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">0</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">.</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" id="equalToBtn" type="button">=</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">+</button></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I have put width of the text 100% and it overflows. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

it was going out because of padding given to the input. hope this helps.

```css
/*The Style file is the following*/

*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
 table{
     border:1px solid silver;
     border-radius:5px;
    }
    
    .btn{
     width:75px;
     height:45px;
    }
    
    #equalToBtn{
     background-color:blue;
     color:white;
     border-color:blue;
    }
    
    #resultText{
     width:100%;
     height:40px;
     margin-right:2px;
    }
```

```html
<!--HTML code-->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
     </head>
     <body>
      <table>
       <tr>
       <td colspan="4"><input type="text" id="resultText"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">7</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">8</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">9</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">/</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">4</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">5</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">6</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">*</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">1</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">2</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">3</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">-</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">0</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">.</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" id="equalToBtn" type="button">=</button></td>
        <td><button class="btn" type="button">+</button></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Is it that making padding 0px to the input does the same thing as box-sizing:border-box

Comment: no `box-sizing:border-box` will adjust the width with padding it will go out of the div but it will make the input smaller. thanks